# How do I change the image that appears on the splash screen in Lotus Notes 8.5?

Tags: lotus-notes

When Lotus Notes 8.5 starts there is a splash screen that appears:

[image]

How can I change this? (Note that I am not running Public Beta 2, that's just the image I happened to find in Google results that closely approximated what I am seeing. The one I'm seeing is basically identical minus the "Public Beta 2" text).

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Well, I saw online that you could do this for older versions of the product quite easily. So I made a new little splash screen for fun and then found that what you used to be able to do couldn't be done anymore the same way. So I was curious if there was a new way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Search the applications directory to see if the image is stored freely. If not use something like ResHacker to view the embedded resources. You can then change them at your will.

Comment: I've found and edited every version of splash.bmp on my machine that I can and it hasn't changed the image. This leads me to believe the image is somehow part of the program or something, in which case, I'll give up...